# What is the right syntax for Ruby to do a system call to curl?

Tags: ruby, curl

To refresh Redmine, I need SVN to ping our Redmine installation from our post-commit hook. Our post-commit hook is a Ruby script that generates an email. I'd like to insert a call do this:

`curl --insecure https://redmineserver+webappkey`

This call works from the command line but when I try to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

REFRESH_DRADIS_URL = "https://redmineserver+webappkey"
system("/usr/bin/curl", "--insecure", "#{REFRESH_DRADIS_URL}")
```

It doesn't work. How do I do this in ruby? I googled 'ruby system curl' but I just got a bunch of links to integrate curl into ruby (which is NOT what I'm interested in).

Comment: By the way: useless use of string interpolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such a simple problem, I wouldn't bother with shelling out to `curl`, I'd simply do

```
require 'net/https'

http = Net::HTTP.new('redmineserver+webappkey', 443)

http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

http.get('/')
```

And for more complex problems, I'd *still* not shell out to `curl`, but rather use one of the many Ruby `libcurl` bindings.

Comment: Making this one the answer since it was the first solution that was closest to the one that worked for me. For folks new to Ruby, the first argument to HTTP.new() is the URI of the server. http.get() takes the URL, starting from /as an argument.

Answer (score 7):

There are [many ways](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html)

```
REFRESH_DRADIS_URL = "https://redmineserver+webappkey"
result = `/usr/bin/curl --insecure #{REFRESH_DRADIS_URL}`
```

but I don't think you have to use curl at all. Try this

```
require 'open-uri'
open(REFRESH_DRADIS_URL)
```

If the certificate isn't valid then it gets a little more complicated

```
require 'net/https'
http = Net::HTTP.new("amazon.com", 443)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
resp, data = http.get("/")
```

Comment: I got this an error. (StackOverflow won't let me print the whole thing, so here's the "important part"). Warning: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Comment: `open("#{REFRESH_DRADIS_URL}")` could be simplified to `open(REFRESH_DRADIS_URL)`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what you get for copy & pasting.

Answer (score 6):

```
system ("curl --insecure #{url}")
```

Comment: how do you store the result of the `curl` call? I'm only interested in the HTTP status code

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this recently and tried the following and it worked:

## test.rb

```
class CurlTest
   def initialize()
   end
   def dumpCurl
      test = `curl -v https://google.com 2>&1`
      puts test
   end
end

curlTest = CurlTest.new()
curlTest.dumpCurl
```